# UICollectionView repeating and showing items out of order

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uicollectionview, custom-renderer

I have build a custom renderer for UICollectionView.

I have been having one issue and I ran out of ideas of possible fixes, here it is.

Whenever the user scrolls the UICollectionView, the next items to be displayed in the screen are shown out of order and repeated.

You can find my code here in GitHub: https://github.com/DanielCauser/XamarinHorizontalList

This gif shows exactly what is wrong, some of the list items appear more than once and out of order.

I think it is due to a race condition, where the OS is just loading the data in wherever viewcell it has available at that frame.

[image]

This is my View in Xamarin.Forms:

```
<local:HorizontalViewNative ItemsSource="{Binding Monkeys}"
                            Grid.Row="5"
                            VerticalOptions="Start"
                            ItemHeight="100"
                            ItemWidth="100">
                <local:HorizontalViewNative.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <ContentView>
                                <StackLayout WidthRequest="100"
                                             HeightRequest="100">
                                    <Image Source="{Binding Image}" />

                                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                                               LineBreakMode="MiddleTruncation"
                                               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                               VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </ContentView>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </local:HorizontalViewNative.ItemTemplate>
            </local:HorizontalViewNative>
```

This is My custom control in the Xamarin.Forms project:

```
public class HorizontalViewNative : View
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create("ItemsSource", typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(HorizontalViewNative), default(IEnumerable<object>), BindingMode.TwoWay, propertyChanged: ItemsSourceChanged);

        public static readonly BindableProperty ItemTemplateProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create("ItemTemplate", typeof(DataTemplate), typeof(HVScrollGridView), default(DataTemplate));

        public static readonly BindableProperty ItemHeightProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create("ItemHeight", typeof(int), typeof(HVScrollGridView), default(int));

        public static readonly BindableProperty ItemWidthProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create("ItemWidth", typeof(int), typeof(HVScrollGridView), default(int));

        public IEnumerable ItemsSource
        {
            get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
        }

        public DataTemplate ItemTemplate
        {
            get { return (DataTemplate)GetValue(ItemTemplateProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ItemTemplateProperty, value); }
        }

        public int ItemHeight
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(ItemHeightProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ItemHeightProperty, value); }
        }

        public int ItemWidth
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(ItemWidthProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ItemWidthProperty, value); }
        }

        private static void ItemsSourceChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
            var itemsLayout = (HorizontalViewNative)bindable;
        }
    }
```

This is my Custom Render in the iOS Project(With the UICollectionView, UICollectionViewSource and UICollectionViewCell).

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(HorizontalViewNative), typeof(iOSHorizontalViewRenderer))]
namespace XamarinHorizontalList.iOS
{
    public class iOSHorizontalViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<HorizontalViewNative, UICollectionView>
    {
        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.PropertyName == nameof(HorizontalViewNative.ItemsSource))
            {
                Control.Source = new iOSViewSource(Element as HorizontalViewNative);
                Control.RegisterClassForCell(typeof(iOSViewCell), nameof(iOSViewCell));
            }
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<HorizontalViewNative> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control == null)
            {
                var layout = new UICollectionViewFlowLayout();
                layout.ScrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.Horizontal;

                if (e.NewElement != null)
                {
                    layout.ItemSize = new CGSize(e.NewElement.ItemWidth, e.NewElement.ItemHeight);
                    layout.MinimumInteritemSpacing = 0;
                    layout.MinimumLineSpacing = 0;

                    var rect = new CGRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
                    SetNativeControl(new UICollectionView(rect, layout));
                    Control.BackgroundColor = e.NewElement?.BackgroundColor.ToUIColor();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class iOSViewSource : UICollectionViewSource
    {
        private readonly HorizontalViewNative _view;

        private readonly IList _dataSource;

        public iOSViewSource(HorizontalViewNative view)
        {
            _view = view;
            _dataSource = view.ItemsSource?.Cast<object>()?.ToList();
        }

        public override nint NumberOfSections(UICollectionView collectionView)
        {
            return 1;
        }

        public override nint GetItemsCount(UICollectionView collectionView, nint section)
        {
            return _dataSource != null ? _dataSource.Count : 0;
        }

        public override UICollectionViewCell GetCell(UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            iOSViewCell cell = (iOSViewCell)collectionView.DequeueReusableCell(nameof(iOSViewCell), indexPath);
            var dataContext = _dataSource[indexPath.Row];
            Debug.WriteLine(((Monkey)dataContext).Name);
            if (dataContext != null)
            {
                var dataTemplate = _view.ItemTemplate;
                ViewCell viewCell;
                var selector = dataTemplate as DataTemplateSelector;
                if (selector != null)
                {
                    var template = selector.SelectTemplate(_dataSource[indexPath.Row], _view.Parent);
                    viewCell = template.CreateContent() as ViewCell;
                }
                else
                {
                    viewCell = dataTemplate?.CreateContent() as ViewCell;
                }

                cell.UpdateUi(viewCell, dataContext, _view);
            }
            return cell;
        }
    }

    public class iOSViewCell : UICollectionViewCell
    {
        private UIView _view;

        public iOSViewCell(IntPtr p) : base(p)
        {
        }

        public void UpdateUi(ViewCell viewCell, object dataContext, HorizontalViewNative view)
        {
            viewCell.BindingContext = dataContext;
            viewCell.Parent = view;

            var height = (int)((view.ItemHeight + viewCell.View.Margin.Top + viewCell.View.Margin.Bottom));
            var width = (int)((view.ItemWidth + viewCell.View.Margin.Left + viewCell.View.Margin.Right));
            viewCell.View.Layout(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height));

            if (Platform.GetRenderer(viewCell.View) == null)
            {
                Platform.SetRenderer(viewCell.View, Platform.CreateRenderer(viewCell.View));
            }
            var renderer = Platform.GetRenderer(viewCell.View).NativeView;

            if (_view == null)
            {
                renderer.ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit;
                ContentView.AddSubview(renderer);
            }
            _view = renderer;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On iOS `UICollectionView` will reuse cell because you call `DequeueReusableCell(nameof(iOSViewCell), indexPath);`.

It means when the collection view first loads its content, it asks its data source to provide a view for each visible item. To simplify the creation process for your code, the collection view requires that you always dequeue views, rather than create them explicitly in your code. See [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview) for more details.

So your `UICollectionView` seems working well at first with initial four cells. But after you scroll it the cell's content becomes messed because of this statement which is **not correct**:

```
if (_view == null)
{
    renderer.ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit;
    ContentView.AddSubview(renderer);
}
```

When `UICollectionView` try to reuse Cell from queue the property `_view` will not be null, so `ContentView` will not add a new subView. Then your cell presents old images and texts. You can try this to fix it:

```
//if (_view == null)
//{
//Remove all subViews from contentView when the cell being reused.
foreach(UIView subView in ContentView.Subviews)
{
    subView.RemoveFromSuperview();
}
renderer.ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit;
ContentView.AddSubview(renderer);
//}
//_view = renderer;
```

But what I want to recommend you to do is: since you try to use renderer, why not try native methods to create your cell, datasource?

Firstly, modify your cell's construct like:

```
UIImageView imgView;
UILabel label;
public iOSViewCell(IntPtr p) : base(p)
{
    imgView = new UIImageView(new CGRect(0, 0, 100, 80));
    ContentView.AddSubview(imgView);
    imgView.ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit;

    label = new UILabel(new CGRect(0, 80, 100, 20));
    label.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center;
    label.LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.MiddleTruncation;
    ContentView.AddSubview(label);
}
```

Also change the `UpdateUi()` method:

```
public void UpdateUi(object dataContext)
{
    Monkey monkey = dataContext as Monkey;
    imgView.Image = UIImage.FromBundle(monkey.Image);
    label.Text = monkey.Name;
}
```

The last step is modifying the `GetCell()` event:

```
public override UICollectionViewCell GetCell(UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    iOSViewCell cell = (iOSViewCell)collectionView.DequeueReusableCell(nameof(iOSViewCell), indexPath);
    var dataContext = _dataSource[indexPath.Row];
    if (dataContext != null)
    {
        cell.UpdateUi(dataContext);
    }
    return cell;
}
```

In this way the scrollView may scroll more smoothly.

Comment: Thank you for your Response Land Lu. I will try to remove the subviews from the ContentView, I was doing that but on the ContentView like ContentView.RemoveFromSuperview();

What you suggested about trying the native controls makes sense, but on this project, I want to be able to have any type of UI as my list ItemTemplate and any type of data as my binding context, that is why I am trying to keep it as generic as possible.

Comment: Removing the subviews from the ContentView and adding the new views I had worked perfectly! THank you very much!!